# Attribute error object has no attribute

Tags: python

I just wanted to try some classes then I am stuck in Basics ..My code is below :

```
class Prob():
    def _init_(self):
        self._count = 0
    def _ProbCal(self):
        print(self._count)
d = Prob()
d._ProbCal()
```

error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ProbCalculation.py", line 8, in <module>
    d._ProbCal()
  File "ProbCalculation.py", line 6, in _ProbCal
    print(self._count)
AttributeError: 'Prob' object has no attribute '_count'
```

Comment: `def __init__(self)` .. Double underscore

Answer (score 1):

Your `__init__` function requires double underscores at the start and end of the  method name:

```
class Prob():
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0

    def _ProbCal(self):
        print(self._count)

d = Prob()
d._ProbCal()
```

Comment: thank you very much , I feel so silly for this stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

`_init_` Must have double underscores like so:

```
class Prob():
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0
    def _ProbCal(self):
        print(self._count)
d = Prob()
d._ProbCal()
```

Comment: thank you very much , I feel so silly for this stupid mistake